# Laravel 4.2 composer update -- What is this?

Tags: php, laravel-4

When I run `composer update` I see some non-ascii characters shown below. Sometimes after printing the characters the update takes too long until it times out and I have to run it again:

Windows 7 Pro, WAMP

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
O┌╠ßsÅF°N]╥Jê|╣╡N┌╠ßrÅF°O]╥Jë|╣╡N┌╠ <<<======== LOOK HERE .... WHAT IS THIS?
$
```

However, when I run `composer dump-autoload` autoload files are successfully generated:

```
$ composer dump-autoload
Generating autoload files
$
```

This was not always the case; this has been happening now for about a month  now. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "jenssegers/mongodb": "*",
        "webpatser/laravel-countries": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

**RESOLVED** (spoke too soon ... so random I don't know what to make of it!)

`composer update` is completing cleanly now. However, I cannot tell which of the following steps, if any, resolved the issue, as I did not follow good troubleshooting practices of running `composer update` after each step. Here is a transcript of all the commands executed so far:

```
$ composer update
....
O┌╠ßsÅF°N]╥Jê|╣╡N┌╠ßrÅF°O]╥Jë|╣╡N┌╠

$ composer dump-autoload   //CLEAN

$ php artisan dump-autoload //CLEAN

$ composer update --no-scripts //CLEAN

$ php artisan optimize  //CLEAN

$ php artisan clear-compiled  //CLEAN

$ composer update   //CLEAN
$ composer update   //CLEAN

$ composer update
.....
O┌╠ßsÅF°N]╥Jê|╣╡N┌╠ßrÅF°O]╥Jë|╣╡N┌╠ //OOPS -- there it is again :(

$ php artisan clear-compiled  //CLEAN

$ composer update   //CLEAN

$ composer update   //NOT CLEAN

$ composer update   //CLEAN
```

Comment: Maybe something in a post-update-cmd script?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Where would I look if that's the case?

Comment: In your project's composer.json file, scripts->post-update-cmd. Maybe something was added there for a package you installed recently. I'm just guessing, really.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, I have included `composer.json` in case that helps. Thanks.

Comment: try ```composer update --no-scripts``` to exclude the scripts.

Comment: Output:
`$ composer update --no-scripts
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

$`

Comment: `php artisan optimize` is most likely what generated the original garbled output, try that.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. It completes cleanly: 
`$ php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader

$`

Comment: If you remove scripts from your composer.json and run `composer update`, does it still happen? If it does, try adding `-vvv` to your `composer update` command and see if you can pinpoint exactly when it happens.

Comment: Not removed scripts yet. Did `php artisan clear-compiled` and then `composer update` and for the first time in a while it completed without spewing out the garbage. Will run `composer update` again to confirm.